Vulnerability in System.Text.Json and System.Text.RegularExpressions after update to .NET 9
I have updated the sdk to .NET 9 and I started getting these warnings (that are escalated to error due to a setting):

Package 'System.Text.Json' 8.0.0 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hh2w-p6rv-4g7w


Package 'System.Text.RegularExpressions' 4.3.0 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cmhx-cq75-c4mj

It seems that .NET itself is referencing these packages, e.g. (I get this package in package.lock.json right under "net8.0"):
"System.Data.Common": {
        "type": "Transitive",
        "resolved": "4.3.0",
        "contentHash": "lm6E3T5u7BOuEH0u18JpbJHxBfOJPuCyl4Kg1RH10ktYLp5uEEE1xKrHW56/We4SnZpGAuCc9N0MJpSDhTHZGQ==",
        "dependencies": {
          "System.Collections": "4.3.0",
          "System.Globalization": "4.3.0",
          "System.IO": "4.3.0",
          "System.Resources.ResourceManager": "4.3.0",
          "System.Runtime": "4.3.0",
          "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.3.0",
          "System.Text.RegularExpressions": "4.3.0",
          "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.3.0"
        }
      },

I have checked and there is no System.Data.Common that is newer, what is the correct way to resolve this issue?
It seems rather weird that MS has released .NET 9 with a more strict check and their own latest library System.Data.Common is referencing the outdated and vulnerable package.

Both System.Text.Json and System.Text.RegularExpressions version in .NET 9 is 9, not 8. They're part of the runtime itself so don't need any NuGet packages. You must be using a package that depends on older versions. System.Data.Common is part of the runtime itself in .NET Core, not something you add through a package. I suspect the project is referencing a package that only targets .NET Standard 2.0 and so references the compatibility System.Data.Common package

I have updated the sdk on my machine, but I still reference the net8.0 in my project (updating to 9.0 though produces the same errors). I see I typed a bit wrong, sorry for the confusion

Update the packages as well. How did this project end up referencing an ancient System.Text.RegularExpressions package that doesn't match STJ's version? Why isn't it using the runtime types? Some other package is referencing those

What package depends on System.Data.Common or System.Text.RegularExpressions ? It's obvious from "type": "Transitive", that these are transitive dependencies. Check in project.assets.json

4.3.1 is the latest System.Text.RegularExpression version, it does not match system.text.json version

No it's not. It's part of the runtime itself, not a package. What you refer to is only the .NET Standard compatibility shim, not the actual regex classes in .NET 9

MiniProfiler.AspNetCore.Mvc is using it. Thanks for help, I did not understand that you do not see a full tree in package.lock.json, but have to search a bit to find these. Which means this package should be updated ideally

Thanks for the clarification regarding the shim as well @PanagiotisKanavos, I did not understand that these are built-in packages that are not available on nuget

MiniProfiler depends on the MiniProfiler.Shared package which targets .NET Standard 2.0 and requires the shims. As for the full tree check in project.assets.json not package.lock.json

How would I use the latest version of the package from dotnet itself? I have done this for STJ

But the System.Text.RegularExpression is only 4.3.1 available, I cannot do 8.*

There's a worse culprit for such errors - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient which adds dependencies to Azure.Identity, something which seems to have a new vulnerability every other month.

Is it also a correct way of fixing such errors? Refernce the newer version of the package directly?

There's a GH issue for this. Now that .NET 6 is dead, there's no reason to target it and the dependencies in MiniProfiler.Shared can be removed. If you're in a hurry you could clone the repo yourself, change the target to net8.0 and remove the unnecessary dependencies

I see, thanks a lot for you help! I am wondering still if there is a way to directly reference the versions included in the dotnet itself (as you mention there are higher versions there than shims available). Or is this not possible/smart to do?

You could turn NuGet warnings back down using
<NuGetAuditMode>direct</NuGetAuditMode>

This not recommended as it will hide vulnerabilities.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/9.0/nugetaudit-transitive-packages
You could stop targeting .net Standard and only target .net8+. This might not be an option for child packages.
You could add references like you have done in the short term.
You could turn the warnings down for just the restore step. e.g.
<NuGetAuditSuppress Include="https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cmhx-cq75-c4mj" />

You could uninstall the .net 9 SDK.
The best answer is to only use NuGet packages that don't have vulnerabilities but this depends on the publishers.
